# angular ng-upload-file $watch not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have the following codes.

HTML :

```
<div class="button" ngf-select ng-model="files">Upload using model $watch</div>
<img width="80" height="80" ngf-src="files[0]" ngf-default-src="'/thumb.jpg'" ngf-accept="'image/*'">
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
$scope.$watch('[files]', function () {
        $scope.upload($scope.files);
        console.log($scope.files);
    });

    $scope.log = '';

    $scope.upload = function (files) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                Upload.upload({
                    url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                    fields: {
                        'username': $scope.username
                    },
                    file: file
                }).progress(function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    $scope.log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' +
                                evt.config.file.name + '\n' + $scope.log;
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.log = 'file: ' + config.file.name + ', Response: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + '\n' + $scope.log;
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

The code above works fine in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/18yao91v/) also I followed this [documentation](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) carefully. And I got it working when you select an image on the window explorer it appears on the `img width="80" height="80" ngf-src="files[0]" ngf-default-src="'/thumb.jpg'" ngf-accept="'image/*'">`. So far so good.

But `$scope.$watch` seems to only works onload and `console.log($scope.files);` prints `undefined`, on the second time that angular should call the digest loop it doesn't call `$scope.$watch` preventing it to call `$scope.upload($scope.files);` which will perform the upload. Nothing is happening as if the `ng-model="files"` doesn't work. I spent several hours debugging this please help.

Comment: could you try `$scope.$watch('files'`, function(){}, true);`

Comment: @PankajParkar I already did Sir. Not luck.  :(

Comment: Do you use ng-if or ng-repeat? It might be a scope issue. Try `ng-model="$parent.files"`

Comment: @danial no `ng-if` no `ng-repeat` what does the `$parent` do?

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle showing the issue? $parent uses the parent scope in case you are using ngf-select inside a directive that creates it's own scope.